# Unable to Install Virtualenv with Pip on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, pip, virtualenv

As root, I'm trying to set up a dev server running Debian Squeeze with a virtualenv directory.

My plan was to run the following commands:

```
apt-get install python-pip
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install virtualenv
```

On the last command, however, I got the following error and now get it whenever I run pip:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import vcs, get_src_requirement, import_vcs_support
ImportError: cannot import name import_vcs_support
```

Google has little to offer on the subject. Subsequently installed `python-dev` and `build-essential` but the problem persists.

Comment: Running `ls -al /usr/bin/pip` shows `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Mar 13 02:20 /usr/bin/pip -> ../share/pyshared/pip/__init__.py`. I easy_install'd pip and then linked `/usr/bin/pip` to `/usr/local/bin/pip-2.6` and that seems to have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears something got screwed up while pip was updating itself.

I worked around the issue by re-installing pip using easy_install:

```
easy_install pip
```

And then linking to that version:

```
ln -sv /usr/local/bin/pip-2.6 /usr/bin/pip
```

---

**(EDIT)**

Here's the complete sequence from scratch:

```
apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install virtualenv
```

This is where the import error happened. To recover, continue with these steps:

```
easy_install pip
rm /usr/bin/pip
ln -sv /usr/local/bin/pip-2.6 /usr/bin/pip
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install virtualenv
```

It may be possible to avoid this by just using easy_install from the start, but I don't have a clean Debian install at the moment to confirm this.

Comment: Do now use easy_install or pip install as root on any package-based distribution!
https://workaround.org/easy-install-debian

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a full answer, but I find code in comments really hard to read.

I was able to install pip on Debian 7.3 amd64 without any errors using

```
user@host:~$ sudo aptitude install python-pip
  ...
user@host:~$ pip install virtualenv
  ...
```

As I skipped the self-upgrade, this obviously does not get me pip in the [currently latest version 1.5.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip); virtualenv is [up to date (1.11.2)](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/news.html) though:

```
user@host:~$ pip --version
pip 1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
user@host:~$ virtualenv --version
1.11.2
```